# Is Web.xml file required when using glassfish web server?

Tags: webserver

Do we need to add web.xml file when we are using glassfish web server? but in tomcat we don't need to add web.xml file.  Is this correct? Asking as Im getting an error when i don't add web.xml file in glassfish.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just note will probably help others answer your question if you update it to include the error message you are seeing.